# How to convert between "similar" 3D-vector classes in java?

Tags: java, type-conversion

I'm writing a geom package as part of a Java library that has its own vector class:

```java
package mypackage.geom;

public class Vector3D {
  public float x;
  public float y;
  public float z;

  public Vector3D(float x, float y, float z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
  ...
}
```

My library is expected to complement the functionality of a third party library which also implements a vector class, say `Vec3D`. The `Vec3D` class has the same fields (`float x`, `float y` and `float z`) and constructor signatures as my `Vector3D` class. I just want to use the third party vector class everywhere a `Vector3D` parameter is expected in my library (e.g., Suppose I have a `Camera` class that has a `setPosition(Vector3D vector3D)` method, and I want be able to pass a `Vec3D` instance to it).

This is possible in C++. For instance, one can declare an universal explicit converter constructor from any class to Vector3D, in the following way:

```cpp
template <class C>
explicit Vector3D(const C& c) : x(c[0]), y(c[1]), z(c[2]) {}
```

all that it requires is that the foreigner class implements the `operator[]`. I was wondering how to implement something similar in Java, if possible at all.

Comment: Since your library is extending this other library, is there a reason you aren't simply using the `Vec3D` class? If for some reason you do have to have your own class, would it be feasible to define `Vector3D` to extend `Vec3D`?

Comment: I should have said "complement" not "extend". I updated the original text.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options, none of them as nice as what you show. First, of course, you can write an explicit constructor:

```
Vector3d(Vec3d v) {this.x = v.x; this.y = v.y; this.z = v.z; }
```

Second, you could provide a constructor that worked for any vector type that implemented an interface you would define (call it "V":)

```
Vector3d(V v) {this.x = v.getX(); this.y = v.getY(); this.z = v.getZ(); }
```

Of course, the chance that any random vector-like thing would implement V is pretty much 0, unless you're a standards body of some kind.

You could also provide a constructor that takes a `double[]`, under the assumption that most such types will provide a `toArray()` sort of method:

```
Vector3d(double[] v) {this.x = v[0]; this.y = v[1]; this.z = v[2]; }
```

This would make it relatively easy to convert most other vector classes into yours, without adding a custom constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think this comes closest to your converter constructor from any (unknown) kind of class:

```
public vec(Object any)
{
    try {
        x = any.getClass().getDeclaredField("x").getDouble(any);
        y = any.getClass().getDeclaredField("y").getDouble(any);
        z = any.getClass().getDeclaredField("z").getDouble(any);
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        throw(new RuntimeException("vec cannot handle class in constructor: "+any.getClass(),e));
    }
}
```